# Im trying to insert a rows in sqlite embedded db in java. after inserting changes are visible in that program alone

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I'm trying to insert rows in SQLite embedded DB in java. after adding changes are visible in that program alone. I can't see the changes in sqlite manager. When I try to insert a row in sqlite manager values that inserted which are shown in the program gets deleted. And showing those row that I added using sqlite manager. Please help..

connection class

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class HsqlConn {

//public static void main(String[] args) {
 public static Connection hconn = null;
 public static Statement hstmt = null; 
 public static PreparedStatement pst = null;
public static void hConnectDb(){

try{
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    ClassLoader classLoader =   Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource("PS/PSDB.sqlite");
    hconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:"+resource);
}
catch(Exception se){
  //Handle errors for JDBC
  se.printStackTrace();
}



}
}
```

main class using that db

```
private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        hConnectDb();
        String sql1 = "Insert into Bill (billNo,date,principal,principalText,custId,dueDate) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = hconn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pst.setString(1,BillNoField.getText());
        pst.setString(2,dateField1.getText());
        pst.setString(3,PrincipalField.getText());
        pst.setString(4,PrincipaTextField.getText());
        pst.setString(5,custIdField.getText());
        pst.setString(6,dueDateField.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        pst.close();
        hconn.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "saved");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [sqlite-jdbc](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc), connection URL strings beginning with "jdbc:sqlite::resource:" are for loading **read-only** SQLite databases:

> 2009 May 19th: sqlite-jdbc-3.6.14.1 released.
>
> - This version supports "jdbc:sqlite::resource:" syntax to access read-only DB files contained in JAR archives, or external resources specified via URL, local files address etc. (see also the

You need to [specify a file in the filesystem](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#how-to-specify-database-files) containing your SQLite database. On Windows, an example is:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/work/mydatabase.db");
```

and on UNIX-like systems, an example is:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/leo/work/mydatabase.db");
```